# Selenium cannot find elements on Google service while minimalised or headless mode

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I try to create a program which will automate fetching data from one of the Google services. By using chrome and watir (which is basically a Ruby library build on top of the Selenium). Everything works fine as long as I keep my browser open. But when I minimize window, my program is not even able to pass a login process since it cannot find certain elements. This is my code to login:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: { detach: true }
@browser.goto BASE_URL
@browser.text_field(name: 'identifier').set USER_EMAIL
@browser.element(xpath: '//*[@id="identifierNext"]').click
@browser.text_field(xpath: '//input[@type="password"]').set USER_PASSWORD
@browser.element(xpath: '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/div[2]').click
```

When my browser is minimize, during attempt to set a password I get this error message:

> *** Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException Exception: element located, but timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for
> #<Watir::TextField: located: true; {:xpath=>"//input[@type="password"]", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be
> present

And it works just fine as an open window. Even if I maximize the window during whole process program is suddenly able to locate missing input fields. The same story goes in many other points further. Program is not able to locate some elements unless chrome window is open.

Needless to say it works even worse in headless mode and I'm basically not able to locate any of those elements in html code.

As far as I understand Google services frontend side are build with Angular framework which inject html code dynamically. But shouldn't selenium pretend to act like a regular user and trigger the same responses on minimized and open window (and the headless mode as well)?

- **Is is some kind of blockade from Google to prevent this kind of automated proces and how can I bypass it?**
- **Is this an issue with Chrome and switching for e.g. Firefox would fix it?**
- **Can I implement some additional actions to actually mimic human interaction and pretend that my Chrome window is open?**

Comment: It should behave as expected when minimized. Does it work in Firefox? If you're on Linux the headless gem works better than Chrome headless mode.

Comment: try [assing user agent

Comment: “ But shouldn't selenium pretend to act like a regular user and trigger the same responses on minimized and open window”
How does a user click things on a minimized window?  Selenium cannot both “act like a regular user” and at the same time do things a user cannot, such as interact with a minimized browser window.

Comment: Information as to play for and browser would be useful.